# how to write update query to clear selected data in database?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has columns assign_date and tec_id in complains table. I add data to assign_date and tec_id fields by update the query. What I want to do is clear that two columns using an update query. I cannot drop data. So I cannot use a delete query. How do I do that?

assign_date has DateTime data type and,
tec_id has int datatype.

what I tried was,

```
    $id=0;
    $date=date("0000-00-00 00:00:00");
 
    $sql = 'UPDATE complains SET tec_id="NULL", assign_date="NULL" WHERE refno=?';
```

[image]

thank you.

Comment: Define  'clear', and show us what you tried

Comment: These are 2 of many columns? Are they nullable? Are there any foreign keys on either of these 2 columns? Are there any generated columns based on either of these 2 columns? Are there any views? (you get the point) .. Please publish full table definition.

Comment: clear means I want to set tec_id to 0 and assign_date to "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Comment: What I see from the image these fields do not allow null values.

Comment: @caner i edited table to allow null values for those fields

Comment: Is your problem with the date? 'To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-date.html what do you have it sql mode set to ? Also do you prefer to set dates to 0 or would null do?

Comment: null will be okay

Answer (score 0):

`update complains set assign_date=null, tech_id=null where id=:id`
Of course these fields should allow null values.

Comment: you send paremeters null as a string try just NULL not "NULL"

Comment: It worked dear! error happened because there were undefined variables in my query.  Thank You